# Does Pony support SSL/TLS for GMail (Yes!)

Tags: ruby, sinatra, heroku, pony

Does the Pony gem support e-mail with SSL/TLS? I'm trying to (easily) send e-mail with Google Apps on Heroku.

Thanks!

After jumping through several hoops, I found a combination of solutions that worked for me: http://417east.com/thoughts/2009/austin/heroku-gmail-sinatra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a link to a thread that should have your answers http://groups.google.com/group/sinatrarb/browse_thread/thread/97619e0469c29f30?pli=1

Comment: Cool, it lead me to Hiroshi's branch.

Answer (score -1):

All ruby mailing libs are based on standard class Net::SMTP which supports only 3 types of authentication (PLAIN, LOGIN and CRAM MD5). So, they`re not supporting SSL connections.

But there are some hacks with Sockets and SSL library. Check out these links:

- http://gusortiz.wordpress.com/2009/01/05/sending-mail-smtp-gmail-with-attachment-using-ruby-on-rails-actionmailer/
- http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/net_smtp_tls_support